# Symfony4 Embed form issue

Tags: php, symfony

I'm learning php and Symfony. I made Ring entity and RingPhoto entity. I want to add a form for RingPhoto inside a form for Ring entity, so I can edit ring information and photo url; ring information will be under Ring entity and photo url will be under Ring photo.

this is Ring entity

'''

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Customize\Entity\RingPhoto", mappedBy="ring")
     */
    private $ringPhoto;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ringPhoto = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|RingPhoto[]
     */
    public function getRingPhoto(): Collection
    {
        return $this->ringPhoto;
    }
```

'''

and this is ringPhoto Entity

'''

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customize\Entity\Ring", inversedBy="ringPhoto")
     */
    private $ring;

    public function getRings(): ?Ring
    {
        return $this->ring;
    }

    public function setRings(?Ring $ring): self
    {
        $this->ring = $ring;

        return $this;
    }
```

'''

and this is RingPhotoType

'''

```
   class RingPhotoType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('image1', FileType::class, [
            'label' => 'file1'
        ])
        ->add('image2', FileType::class, [
            'label' => 'file1'
        ])
        ->add('image3', FileType::class, [
            'label' => 'file1'
        ]);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => RingPhoto::class,
    ]);
}
```

}

'''

this is Controller

'''

```
   public function UpdateRing($id, Request $request){
  
  $doct = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $rn = $doct->getRepository(Ring::class)->find($id);
 
  if(!$rn){
     throw $this->createNotFoundException(
        'No Ring found for id.'.$id
     );
  }
  
  $form = $this->createFormBuilder($rn)
     ->add('product_group_id', HiddenType::class,['data'=> 1])
     ->add('ring_name', TextType::class)
     ->add('ring_type', TextType::class)
     ->add('ring_shape', TextType::class)
     ->add('size', ChoiceType::class, array('choices' => array(
        '0.5'=>0.5,
        '1'=>1,
        '1.5'=>1.5,
        '2'=>2,
        '2.5'=>2.5,
        '3'=>3,
        '3.5'=>3.5,
        '4'=>4,
   

        )))
     ->add('price', IntegerType::class)
     ->add('ringPhoto', CollectionType::class,[
        'entry_type' => RingPhotoType::class,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'entry_options' =>[
           'label' => false,
        ],
        'allow_add' => true,
        'by_reference' => false,
        'prototype' => true
     ])
     ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Update'])
     ->getForm();

     $form->handleRequest($request);

     
     if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $ring = $form->getData();
        $doct = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        //tell doctrine to save the product
        $doct->persist($ring);
        
        //executes the queries
        $doct->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('test');
     }
     else{
        return[
           'form' => $form->createView(),
     ];
     }
```

}

'''

and this is the twig

'''

```
   {% extends 'default_frame.twig' %}

  {% block main %}

   <h3>SamplePage!!</h3>
  <div>hello this is Update page</div>
   {{form_start(form)}}
{{form_widget(form)}}
 {{form_row(form.ringPhoto)}}
{{form_end(form)}}

 {% endblock %}
```

'''

so it's kinda working, having no errors. But in the view, under the price, I can only see the name Ring Photo.
It does not show image1, image2, image3 from RingPhotoType.php that I can fill in :S
how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Could you use only '{{ form(form) }}', to check ?

Comment: yep, I tried it but still the same.
I add random stuff in builder in RingPhotoType, but it doesn't say anything like [Neither the property "aaa" nor one of the methods "getAaa()", "aaa()", "isAaa()", "hasAaa()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "Customize\Entity\Ring".] 
so I guess the builder does not recognize stuff inside RingPhotoType :S

Comment: Can I see all your Controller function ?

Comment: Sure! I updated Controller function here

Comment: As for your Code Formatting attempt, it would work better if you use three back-ticks ``` instead of three single quotation marks '''

Answer (score 0):

Oh I fixed it.
I added nullable=true to image1, 2, 3 in RingPhoto Entity and somehow it solved the problem

Comment: Nice, just some improvements : 
 - pass your repository as dependency injection
 - put the formtype in another file like your ringPhotoType
 - remove the else , because you use `return`
 - use `$form->getErrors();` to get the form errors.

Regards,

Comment: i think this is `'by_reference' => false`